# PHP Contador Hora, minuto y segundos

Tags: php

tengo el siguiente código para un contador en PHP:

> date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');

```
function evento()
{
    time();
    $today = strtotime('today 12:00');
    $tomorrow = strtotime('tomorrow 12:00');
    $time_now = time();
    $timeLeft = ($time_now > $today ? $tomorrow : $today) - $time_now;
    return gmdate("H:i:s", $timeLeft);
}   

echo evento();
```

me da como resultado:

> 00:07:18

Mi cuestión y duda (podría ser demasiado novata la pregunta). ¿Cómo podria hacer para que me arroje lo siguiente?

```
echo evento();
```

> 00 Horas, 07 Minutos, 18 Segundos.

Sé que con Javascript es posible, pero me gustaría usar PHP para esto.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías modificar tu función `evento` y usar [`strftime`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strftime.php) en lugar de `gmdate`.

Así por ejemplo:

```
<?php

    date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
    function evento()
    {
        time();
        $today = strtotime('today 12:00');
        $tomorrow = strtotime('tomorrow 12:00');
        $time_now = time();
        $timeLeft = ($time_now > $today ? $tomorrow : $today) - $time_now;
        return strftime("%H Horas, %M minutos, %S segundos", $timeLeft);
    }   

    echo evento();

?>
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://rextester.com/RSSUY12184)

Comment: Gracias! usando `strftime ` me ha solucionado todo, Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Hola, lamento molestar, En mi ejemplo me da: `02:35:21`, debido a que puse que se reinicie cada 24 horas a las **12:00** hora del centro de México, pero usando el tuyo me da como resultado `20 Horas, 35 minutos, 21 segundos`. ¿A qué se debe?

Comment: Aquí dejo el ejemplo: http://rextester.com/RYDZB10357

Comment: Ya me han ayudado con este pequeño detalle, Gracias! :D

Answer (score 1):

Algo no tan sofisticado se me ocurre , emplear `printf` , puede añadir el siguiente código dentro o fuera de la función que ya tiene implementada *(dentro de la función tendría que acceder `gmdate("H:i:s", $timeLeft)` en lugar de la llamada a la función)*.

```
$vars = explode(":", evento());
printf(' %s Horas ,  %s Minutos , %s Segundos', $vars[0], $vars[1],$vars[2]);
```

También puede emplear la función [vsprintf](http://php.net/manual/es/function.vsprintf.php) para formatear la cadena pasando un `array` como parámetro .

```
echo vsprintf(' %s Horas ,  %s Minutos , %s Segundos',explode(":" , evento()));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la orientación, esto me servirá para entender mejor en un futuro. La respuesta de Marcos me solvento sin modificar demasiado el código inicial. Gracias!.

Comment: @JosephYang Sí. es la mejor opción. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

A partir de un resultado en formato `strtotime`:

```
return date("H", $timeleft)." Horas, ".date("i", $timeleft)." Minutos,".date("s", $timeleft)." Segundos";
```

Comment: Gracias @Carmen, hoy aprendí mas acerca de `strtotime`. Se agradece el tiempo para contestar a mi pregunta, de verdad Gracias!.